# Nav float right

Tags: css, fixed, nav

I am trying to create a two-part nav bar with options on both the left and right side of the page (its a visual thematic thing for my page, there are supposed to be branches of a tree with leaves being the buttons).

Currently I have them html-coded like this (these 2 png's are just placeholders for now):

```
<nav>
<img src="images/nav-menu-left-temp.png" alt=""/>
<img id="navright" src="images/nav-menu-right-temp.png" alt=""/>
</nav>
```

And here's the CSS I have applied.

```
nav
{
    position: fixed;
}
#navright
{
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
```

I would like them to both have fixed position to the top of the page, but for the left nav bar I need it to be also fixed to the right side of the page if possible (so it looks like a branch extending from off the screen). I was hoping float: right would do the job with the help of fixed but there seems to be a margin on the left side between the edge of the browser and the bar image(s). The page width is currently set to auto. I had hoped it would allow it to scale correctly.

Screenshot of what I have:
http://i723.photobucket.com/albums/ww238/cerberosg/nav1_zpsumvws3h7.jpg

What I'm trying to achieve:
http://i723.photobucket.com/albums/ww238/cerberosg/nav2_zpsxpqonads.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a navigation bar like that, this is what I remeber from the CSS and HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class = "pull-left">
       <li><img src="images/nav-menu-left-temp.png" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class = "pull-right">
       <li><img id="navright" src="images/nav-menu-right-temp.png" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    display: inline;
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, you're using bootstrap classes here.  The question doesn't indicate bootstrap is involved.

Comment: oh, sorry! I didn't have any link to bootstrap though

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't quite work for me. might've been that there was something wrong on my end. I ended up using cale_b's solution, it worked very neatly for me, but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that the `nav` element is not full width.  Try being a bit more explicit with the `nav` element layout, using some styles like so:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You are on the right track.  I've put together a fiddle for you to look at / play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/7qxrsrrw/